# Cannot access area of site using www, without it works

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, dns, no-www

Struggling with this one.

I recently bought hosting and domain name. I have put a holding page on the site, plus installed wordpress in the directory `/wordpress`.

Going to `http://www.the-creative-collective.co.uk/` with the full `www` in front works fine.

Going to it without the `www` I get my hosting provider default page.

Going to `http://www.the-creative-collective.co.uk/wordpress` I get my default hosting page.

I cannot log into Wordpress, I cannot work on my site. It's really frustrating.

I have tried flushing my DNS but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please kindly ask your provider to check the binding again. I believe the problem is only about binding. :)